# How can this code be constexpr? (std::chrono)

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr, c++-chrono, c++17

In the standards paper P0092R1, Howard Hinnant wrote:

```
template <class To, class Rep, class Period,
          class = enable_if_t<detail::is_duration<To>{}>>
constexpr
To floor(const duration<Rep, Period>& d)
{
    To t = duration_cast<To>(d);
    if (t > d)
        --t;
    return t;
}
```

How can this code work? The problem is that `operator--` on a `std::chrono::duration` is not a constexpr operation. It is defined as:

```
duration& operator--();
```

And yet this code compiles, and gives the right answer at compile time:

```
static_assert(floor<hours>(minutes{3}).count() == 0, "”);
```

What's up with that?

Comment: FWIW, the original version (P0) of Howard's paper is available here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0092r0.html

Answer (score 11):

The answer is that not all operations in a compile-time routine have to be constexpr; only the ones *that are executed* at compile time.

In the example above, the operations are:

```
hours t = duration_cast<hours>(d);
if (t > d) {} // which is false, so execution skips the block
return t;
```

all of which can be done at compile time.

If, on the other hand, you were to try:

```
static_assert(floor<hours>(minutes{-3}).count() == -1, "”);
```

it would give a compile-time error saying (using clang):

```
error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
        static_assert(floor<hours>(minutes{-3}).count() == -1, "");
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: non-constexpr function 'operator--' cannot be used in a constant expression
                        --t;
                        ^
note: in call to 'floor(minutes{-3})'
        static_assert(floor<hours>(minutes{-3}).count() == -1, "");
```

When writing constexpr code, you have to consider *all the paths* through the code.

P.S. You can fix the proposed `floor` routine thusly:

```
template <class To, class Rep, class Period,
          class = enable_if_t<detail::is_duration<To>{}>>
constexpr
To floor(const duration<Rep, Period>& d)
{
    To t = duration_cast<To>(d);
    if (t > d)
        t = t - To{1};
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Under the rules of [n3597](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3597.html) and [n3652](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3652.html), expressions inside a `constexpr` function do not themselves have to be constant expressions, as long as they don't modify globally visible state.

There's an example of

```
constexpr int f(int a) {
  int n = a;
  ++n;                  // '++n' is not a constant expression
  return n * a;
}
int k = f(4);           // OK, this is a constant expression.
                        // 'n' in 'f' can be modified because its lifetime
                        // began during the evaluation of the expression.
```

Most likely these are the rules that Howard Hinnant followed when writing the paper you mention.

In order to work with the `duration<T>` code in the question, `operator--` would have to be made a `constexpr` function.  Since `constexpr` changes to the library were not final, it's easy to understand how Howard could have relied on such a change.

Comment: Sorry Ben, Marshall has this one exactly right.  The papers you mention are in C++14, and I made this error very recently, using C++14.